# Aborting a build from hudson is still executing the script at target machine

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Bit new to Hudson so this might be silly question for few of you.

I was using Hudson  version 2.2.0 and everything was running fine in there but as soon as I upgraded to latest version available as of now, a new problem came into picture.

i.e. with this new Hudson version, if I abort a build while it is executing, Hudson will show on its console that build has been aborted successfully but still I can see that job being executed at my machine for remaining test case. And a big problem to this is if I am running a job in a loop for 100 times and due to some reasons, I abort it when it reaches at 50th loop, it will still continue for remaining 50 loops.

Any solution to this problem?
I have tried to downgrade to previous version but as soon as it downgrades, none of my jobs are available to me. I can not see any job there. So I have to upgrade it back to latest version.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you, but I can only commiserate. IMO Jenkins cannot abort any job cleanly, and I have taken great efforts to prevent users from having the option of aborting a build, but still they do, and still I have to clean up after them. I am watching this thread with great anticipation.